# How to Show and Hide YouTube's Video Controls

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, html5-video, browser-extension

In a browser extension of mine ([YT Kbd Nav](https://github.com/FanaroEngineering/yt_kbd_nav)), I'm trying to add a shortcut for showing and hiding YouTube's video controls, with the objective of showing the time in the video to the user.

Currently, I use the up and down arrow keys to force them to show, but that changes the volume, so I have to press both arrows one after another to nullify the effect (I guess I could make the shortcut do that instead of messing around with their controls...).

After inspecting the page, I've noticed they don't actually use `<video>` controls apparently, they use custom `<div>`s instead. Does anyone know how to interact with their video controls?

(For my specific use case of the browser extension, I'm also thinking about actually showing the time of the video as a separate overlay, much like MPV or VLC do.)

Comment: Besides the whole YouTube controls thing, I think that even cleaner than artificially clicking on the arrow keys would be using my browser extension's focus feature, tab, and then refocus.

Answer (score -2):

Click on your YouTube account icon on top right corner.
Go to Settings -> Accessibility.
Here you will see an option Accessibility Player.
Off that to hide YouTube controls.

Comment: I don't see any accessibility controls from my settings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).